# Фрагменты или списки

Tags: java, android

Приветствую. Создаю свое первое клиент-серверное приложение, поэтому хочу проконсультироваться с более опытными разработчиками. 
Сама суть вопроса: я получаю с сервера ответ в формате `json`, который может быть 2-х видов, например, `{"response": 0}` и `{"response": [{"count_wall": 20, item: [{"user_id": 12, "title": "title", "body": "description"}, {"user_id": ... }]}]}`. И в зависимости от ответа, я должен вывести либо, что записей нет, либо в виде списка. Т.е. будет 2 `layout` файла: 1. лист списка

[image: лист списка]

2. записей нет:

   [image: нет записей]

Что лучше, под данную ситуацию: использование отдельных фрагментов или реализация списка? Каждый фрагмент или пункт списка должен иметь свой обработчик.

Comment: В вашем случае конечно список, как вы собираетесь использовать в такой ситуации фрагменты

Comment: @pavlofff вот поэтому я и решил проконсультироваться